# DETECT Speaking Language- iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I can covert the speech that a user spokes to text using Open ears (see http://www.politepix.com/openears/yourapp). But How i could detect the language which the user speaks is English, french, chinese etc... Is there any method to understand in which language the user speaks? How can i check this.? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Can I play any thing with this

```
- (NSError *) generateLanguageModelFromArray:(NSArray *)languageModelArray withFilesNamed:(NSString *)fileName;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you are able to do so. I'm backing my claim with the need to set your language in every speech to text application, Siri included. You either have to wait a few more years, or invent a new algorithm which will eventually make you filthy rich.